# Disable keyboard shortcuts bar for ipad custom iOS keyboard (swift3)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, keyboard

I've written a custom iOS keyboard that works fine. On iPads, when I switch between keyboards, my custom keyboard renders and then the shortcut bar gets added to the top (if the shortcuts bar option is turned on in settings - if it's not turned on, I have no issue). Because it's happening in 2 steps the keyboad appears to "bounce". My keyboard takes up less screen real-estate than the default iOS keybard, so it drops down. Then it pops back up as it renders the shortcuts bar.

Is there a way to either override the global setting and force the shortcuts bar off/hidden for my keyboard? Alternative, can I force it on and make it render at the same time as my keyboard is drawn?

Comment: can you show the screen shot

Comment: Not easily, because it happens over a period of a second. If you want to see the shortcuts bar, it's above the qwerty row in [this image](https://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/xlarge/public/field/image/2016/03/keyboard-ipad-shortcut-bar-screens-04.jpeg?itok=JyovCIR6). Imagine that that bar disappears and then reappears.

Comment: add in your proxy `let item = yourTextfieldName.inputAssistantItem //as UITextInputAssistantItem
        item.leadingBarButtonGroups = []
        item.trailingBarButtonGroups = []`

Comment: I'm not using a custom text field. Just whatever the input field is whenever the keyboard is selected. How can I get a handle on the text field in that case?